# Check for last record in table in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this table row

```
  <tbody>
       <tr *ngFor="let data of List | paginate : { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p };
                    let i = index">
                
       <td>{{ data.Name }}</td>
       <td>
       </td>
       ...
       </tr>
   </tbody>
```

i want to check the last record of every page suppose 12 records are there `10` on one page then `2` on other page i want to check the last record on every page and apply css on the last record of every page.

Any solution. Thanks

Comment: Your paginate pipe isn't part of angular's common module. Please include details of this. `ngFor` gives you access to a last template variable `*ngFor="...; let last = last;"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

Option 1: Apply a class conditionally with ngClass

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of List | paginate : { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p }; let last = last" [ngClass]="{ yourclass: last }">
```

Option 2: Select the last tr in your stylesheet

```
tr:last-of-type {
  // your styles
}
```